# List index out of bounds when reading CSV File

Tags: python, csv, indexing, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to simply process some twitter data in which I want to count the most frequent words produced in the dataset.

However, I keep getting the following error on Line 45:

```
IndexError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input 346-f03e745247f4> in <module>()
 43 for line in f:
 44 parts = re.split("^\d+\s", line)
 45 tweet = re.split("\s(Status)", parts[-1])[10]
 46 tweet = tweet.replace("\\n"," ")
 47 terms_all = [term for term in process_tweet(tweet)]
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have added my full code for review, can someone please advise.

```
    import codecs
import re
from collections import Counter
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

word_counter = Counter()

def punctuation_symbols():
    return [".", "", "$","%","&",";",":","-","&amp;","?"]

def is_rt_marker(word):
    if word == "b\"rt" or word == "b'rt" or word == "rt":
        return True
    return False

def strip_quotes(word):
    if word.endswith(""):
        word = word[0:-1]
    if word.startswith(""):
        word = word[1:]
    return word

def process_tweet(tweet):
    keep = []
    for word in tweet.split(" "):
        word = word.lower()
        word = strip_quotes(word)
        if len(word) == 0:
            continue
        if word.startswith("https"):
            continue
        if word in stopwords.words('english'):
            continue
        if word in punctuation_symbols():
            continue
        if is_rt_marker(word):
            continue
        keep.append(word)
    return keep

with codecs.open("C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\USA_TWEETS-out.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f: 
    n = 0
    for line in f:
        parts = re.split("^\d+\s", line)
        tweet = re.split("\s(Status)", parts[1])[0]
        tweet = tweet.replace("\\n"," ")
        terms_all = [term for term in process_tweet(tweet)]
        word_counter.update(terms_all)

        n += 1
        if n == 50:
            break

print(word_counter.most_common(10))
```

Comment: The traceback you shared is referencing different code than what you have pasted below it. Specifically `tweet = re.split("\s(Status)", parts[-1])[10]` compared to `tweet = re.split("\s(Status)", parts[1])[0]`. Could you clarify?

Comment: @etemple1: apologies that is also supposed to be 1,0. I was trying different combinations and the traceback was a generated for a previous iteration. Any ideas as to why [1],[0] wont work? Also to clarify n=0 is setting the index and [1] is defining the line start correct?

Comment: BTW `[term for term in process_tweet(tweet)]` is equivalent to `list(process_tweet(tweet))`, which, in your case, is equivalent to just `process_tweet(tweet)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
parts = re.split("^\d+\s", line)
tweet = re.split("\s(Status)", parts[1])[0]
```

These are likely the problematic lines.

You assume that `parts` did split and has more than 1 element. Splitting can fail to find the split-by string in `line`, so `parts` becomes equal to `[line]`. Then `parts[1]` crashes.

Add a check before the second line. Print the `line` value to better understand what happens.